# Does this Question Pass Muster?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm looking at [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/47169/4152) which asks us to find them a manual online. Should it be allowed on the site? My feeling is no, but I want your opinion.

Comment: I answered that ... But I do think you are correct : along the lines of "people should show evidence of a simple search before they post..."

Answer (score 3):

I would say no, it shouldn't - manuals are copyrighted, so what he is asking for is illegal in many places, and is definitely against SO's terms of service...

Comment: Good point! :o)